# Conditional display of image in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, ivalueconverter

I am currently trying to conditionaly display an image. I read quite a bit about valueConverters and triggers, but i strongly believe that there has to be an easier solution for this easy problem.

The XAML:

```
 <Image Source="C:\Users\Niko\Pictures\red.png" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOn}"></Image>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace MVVM {
public class Globals
{
    int i = 2;

    public bool IsOn
    {
        get
        {
            if (i == 1 )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I played around with the integer **i** to see if the image gets displayed or not. Any advice is greatly apreciated!

Comment: You want to bind a bool to the `Visibility` property of the Image and use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter. IsEnable won't hide an image unless you set the style to change the visibility.

Comment: When using MVVM you can bind the `Visibility` of the `Image` to a `bool` in your ViewModel and use and `IValueConverter` to convert the `bool` to `Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapse`. I would use `bool` and not `Visibility` in my ViewModel because it's the cleaner approach and the ViewModel should not know about the `Visibilty` of an `Image`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind the Image's `Visibility` to IsOn and use the built in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\Niko\Pictures\red.png" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Then add the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` as a static resource in either the `<Window.Resources>` for just that window or `<Application.Resources>` for your whole application.

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
```

Note that `x:Key` is the name that you use to reference the converter after StaticResource.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to put a `Visibility` property in your `ViewModel` and don't want to use converters, you can use a `DataTrigger` (here I don't have a `ViewModel` at all, the image is visible if the `ToggleButton` is checked):

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\Niko\Pictures\red.png">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tg}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>

    <ToggleButton Name="tg" Content="Show" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Comment: Not sure if it's _easier_ though :) (as requested in the question)

Comment: I am currently playing around with this code. I am quite new to XAML, I dont want to use a button, I want to achieve it through a condition in VM for further usage. Could I use **tg** for that purpose?

Comment: @Niko_fhtw you can do <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOn}" Value="False"/> instead, without the button

Comment: @Arie I exchanged your DataTrigger part with your new one and used my VM code. I doesn't hide the picture, no matter which value the integer **i** has.

Comment: @Niko_fhtw do you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on your IsOn property?